# Bounty disappeared after my answer was accepted?

Tags: support, bounties

Answered a question with an open 250 pt bounty that was set to close in 5 days.  The OP resolved the issue themselves, but marked my post as the answer because it was "the most helpful".  However, I didn't get the bounty.

NP, I thought maybe I would get it after the five-day deadline.  But that came and went, no bounty was awarded.  Now, when I go to the question, there's no trace of the question ever having a bounty!

I thought a bounty couldn't be withdrawn after it was offered... what gives?

The question:  [asp.net interop memory limitation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002548/asp-net-interop-memory-limitation)

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4002548/revisions) of the question, you can see clearly that the OP has decided to award **himself** the bounty.

> **Bounty Ended** with [**MK's answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002548/asp-net-interop-memory-limitation/4466341#4466341) chosen by MK

In that case, no bounty is actually awarded - the OP simply loses the 250 rep. bounty, and since no reputation transfer has happened, nothing on the answer indicates this has happened (instead of leaving a [image: [0]] marker on the answer). Also, acceptance of an answer is no longer tied to the awarding of any bounties attached to the question.

Of course, *why* or *should* he do this is debatable, but that would be outside the scope of this question, wouldn't it?

Comment: According to the bounty FAQ, a self-awarded bounty is supposed to leave a `+0`, but it seems you're right regardless.

Comment: I'm okay with him doing that, as he really answered his own question, and my answer was only helpful, not correct. I don't feel cheated in any way.  If I were in his shoes, I probably would have marked my own answer as the answer, but awarded the bounty to someone else, just so the points weren't wasted... what he did was kindof like throwing $250 into a fire because you're not allowed to spend it on yourself.  But that's just my perspective.